# Popup button add to cart "continue shopping" / "order"

Tags: popup, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop version: 1.6.1.10

Theme: templatetrip jewelry

Following the request of my customer who wants to add to cart on all products, I added the file "product-list.tpl" the following code:

{if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 || (isset($add_prod_display) && ($add_prod_display == 1))) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && $product.customizable != 2 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}

```
                        {if (!isset($product.customization_required) || !$product.customization_required) && ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                            {capture}add=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}{if isset($product.id_product_attribute) && $product.id_product_attribute}&amp;ipa={$product.id_product_attribute|intval}{/if}{if isset($static_token)}&token={$static_token}{/if}{/capture}
                            <a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, $smarty.capture.default, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Add to cart'}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute|intval}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" data-minimal_quantity="{if isset($product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity) && $product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity >= 1}{$product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity|intval}{else}{$product.minimal_quantity|intval}{/if}">
                                <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                            </a>
                        {else}
                            <span class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default disabled">
                                <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                            </span>
                        {/if}
```

{/if}

The popup is displayed well and the product is well in cart. But the problem is that the button "continue shopping" and "order" is displayed but impossible to click on it (the hover does not work either).

I tested on the defauld theme and it works well. I conclude that this is a problem from the theme. But which one? : D

Answer (score 0):

Okay its was just a problem of CSS sorry for this post